# How to Only plot Confidence Interval in Seaborn Line Plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there a way to only plot the confidence interval using seaborn lineplot (or another seaborn method)? For example, I used seaborn lineplot to produce this graph:

[image]

To produce this graph I just have something like:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, ax=x, x='day_of_week', y='y_variable', color='lightgrey'
```

Since I have a lot of data points per "day of week" which is "Monday", "Tuesday", etc. I just wanted to use the default 95% CI. Is there a way to just plot the CI without the darker line in the middle (which I assume is the mean)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `linewidth=0`:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.lineplot(data=tips, x='day', y='total_bill', linewidth=0)
```

Output:

[image]